# cannot find -lgsl, cannot find -lgslcblas

Tags: c++, r, gsl, rtools

I am trying to install a R package on windows 10 using "`R CMD INSTALL Rpkg`" and I am getting the following error:

```
C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgsl
C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgslcblas
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
```

I installed R in `C:\R_soft\R\R-4.0.4`, RStudio in `C:\R_soft\RStudio`, and Rtools in `C:\rtools40`. Location of gsl library is `C:\R_soft\R\local323`. I referred https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dynr/vignettes/InstallationForUsers.pdf to install gsl and setup the environmental paths. The package I am trying to install was written in C++.

```
> Sys.which("make")                              
"C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\make.exe"

> Sys.which("gcc") 
"C:\\rtools40\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
```

I am still new to R language. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to set the library directories in some configuration file, or include them in your PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution for the issue. First of all, I do not need to install a separate gsl library to use with R. So, I removed  the gsl library I installed earlier into `C:\R_soft\R\local323`. Then I opened the `msys2` shell in rtools and ran `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gsl`. This installs gsl library to mingw64 folder in rtools (default folder used by rtools to store C++ libraries). See https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-gsl for more about the gsl package information.